# Type of object rendered(CUPS)

Tags: cups

I am making a copy of my RIP for CUPS(pstoraster.I wanted to know the type of the object rendered using ghostscript.

Does anyone have this idea

Answer (score 0):

Here is the documentation for the output of pstoraster, which is merely a script that calls ghostscript:

http://www.cups.org/documentation.php/doc-1.4/spec-raster.html